# subplots with multiple colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot, colorbar

I am trying to plot a figure with 4 subplots and 2 colorbars. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator

from matplotlib import rcParams
rcParams["savefig.dpi"] = 100
rcParams["font.size"] = 18

x1 = np.linspace(100, 1000, 10)
y1 = np.linspace(10, 17, 10)
z1 = np.linspace(4, 18, 10)
t1 = np.linspace(-0.3, 0.4, 10)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharey = True, figsize = (10, 10))

a0 = axes[0][0].scatter(x1, y1, s = 40, c = z1, marker = 'o')
cbar1 = fig.colorbar(a0)
axes[0][0].set_ylabel('y1')
axes[0][0].set_xlabel('x1')
axes[0][0].xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(4))

a1 = axes[0][1].scatter(t1, y1, s = 40, c = z1, marker = 'o')
axes[0][1].xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(4))
axes[0][1].set_xlabel('t1')
cbar1.ax.set_ylabel('z1', rotation = 270)

x2 = np.linspace(450, 900, 20)
y2 = np.linspace(11, 12.5, 20)
z2 = np.linspace(12, 60, 20)
t2 = np.linspace(-0.3, 0.4, 20)

a0 = axes[1][0].scatter(x2, y2, c = z2, marker = 'o')
cbar2 = fig.colorbar(a0)
axes[1][0].set_ylabel('y2')
axes[1][0].set_xlabel('x2')
axes[1][0].xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(4))

a1 = axes[1][1].scatter(t2, y2, c = z2, marker = 'o')
axes[1][0].xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(4))
axes[1][1].set_xlabel('t2')
cbar2.ax.set_ylabel('z2', rotation = 270)

plt.show()
```

Here is the figure:
[image]

**The thing I want to fix is:**

the colorbars are at the far end to the right. I want 1 colorbar to be on the right of the first row and another colorbar to be on the right of the second row (basically, where it simply is).

How can I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enter another parameter to select on which axes to plot the colorbar.
Here is the change in your code:

```py
cbar1 = fig.colorbar(a0, ax=axes[0][1])

cbar2 = fig.colorbar(a0, ax=axes[1][1])
```

Which produce this plot:

[image]